# 2012 Community Moderator Election

Tags: discussion, status-completed, election, moderators

The 2012 Community Moderator Election is now underway!

Community moderator elections have three phases:

1. Nomination phase
2. Primary phase
3. Election phase

Most elections take between two and three weeks, but this depends on how many candidates there are.

Please visit the official election page at

https://gaming.stackexchange.com/election

for more detail, and to participate!

If you have general questions about the election process, or questions for moderator candidates, feel free to ask them here on meta -- just make sure your questions are tagged [election](/questions/tagged/election).

Comment: You're a bit of a broken record, aren't you, @Community? Always asking the same questions...

Comment: I think it was programmed to do that..

Answer (score 5):

```
Ballot file contains 10 candidates and 176 ballots.
No candidates have withdrawn.
Ballot file contains 176 non-empty ballots.

Counting votes for Gaming Moderator Election 2012 using Meek STV.
10 candidates running for 2 seats.

 R|Mark Trap|agent86  |Oak      |Kevin Y  |Ronan For|Wipqozn  |Arda Xi  
  |p        |         |         |         |man      |         |         
  |---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------
  |fredley  |John the |OrigamiRo|Exhausted|Surplus  |Threshold
  |         |Green    |bot      |         |         |         
========================================================================
 1|29.000000|36.000000|64.000000| 6.000000| 9.000000|15.000000| 8.000000
  | 4.000000| 3.000000| 2.000000| 0.000000| 5.333333|58.666667
  |---------------------------------------------------------------------
  | Count of first choices. Candidate Oak has reached the threshold and
  | is elected.
========================================================================
 2|30.333328|37.999992|58.666688| 6.249999| 9.083333|15.583331| 8.416665
  | 4.166666| 3.249999| 2.083333| 0.166666| 0.055576|58.611112
  |---------------------------------------------------------------------
  | Count after transferring surplus votes. Keep factors of candidates
  | who have exceeded the threshold: Oak, 0.916667.
========================================================================
 3|31.333328|38.999992|58.666688| 6.249999| 9.083333|15.583331| 8.416665
  | 4.166666| 3.333332|         | 0.166666| 0.055576|58.611112
  |---------------------------------------------------------------------
  | Count after eliminating OrigamiRobot and transferring votes. All
  | losing candidates are eliminated.
========================================================================
 4|31.333328|40.083325|60.500022| 6.249999| 9.166666|15.749997| 8.416665
  | 4.166666|         |         | 0.333332| 1.944465|58.555557
  |---------------------------------------------------------------------
  | Count after eliminating John the Green and transferring votes. All
  | losing candidates are eliminated.
========================================================================
 5|32.416661|41.083325|61.416689| 6.333332|10.166666|15.749997| 8.416665
  |         |         |         | 0.416665| 2.888910|58.527779
  |---------------------------------------------------------------------
  | Count after eliminating fredley and transferring votes. All losing
  | candidates are eliminated.
========================================================================
 6|33.149667|42.161275|58.527783| 6.505804|10.252902|16.138059| 8.632255
  |         |         |         | 0.632255| 0.071867|58.455916
  |---------------------------------------------------------------------
  | Count after transferring surplus votes. Keep factors of candidates
  | who have exceeded the threshold: Oak, 0.873549.
========================================================================
 7|33.149667|44.540628|60.274881|         |10.252902|17.138059| 9.632255
  |         |         |         | 1.011608| 1.945416|58.329465
  |---------------------------------------------------------------------
  | Count after eliminating Kevin Y and transferring votes. All losing
  | candidates are eliminated.
========================================================================
 8|33.628965|45.330060|58.329495|         |10.309290|17.391805| 9.773225
  |         |         |         | 1.237160| 0.075214|58.254281
  |---------------------------------------------------------------------
  | Count after transferring surplus votes. Keep factors of candidates
  | who have exceeded the threshold: Oak, 0.845355.
========================================================================
 9|33.783610|47.948640|63.401625|         |10.463935|18.546450|         
  |         |         |         | 1.855740| 5.353538|58.048087
  |---------------------------------------------------------------------
  | Count after eliminating Arda Xi and transferring votes. All losing
  | candidates are eliminated.
========================================================================
10|34.938255|49.948640|65.092335|         |         |22.546450|         
  |         |         |         | 3.474320| 7.583774|57.508561
  |---------------------------------------------------------------------
  | Count after eliminating Ronan Forman and transferring votes. All
  | losing candidates are eliminated.
========================================================================
11|37.938255|57.412575|70.164465|         |         |         |         
  |         |         |         |10.484705|17.233508|55.171766
  |---------------------------------------------------------------------
  | Count after eliminating Wipqozn and transferring votes. All losing
  | candidates are eliminated. Candidate agent86 has reached the
  | threshold and is elected.
```

> ## Winners are [agent86](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/13845/agent86) and [Oak](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/122/oak).
>
> [image] [image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This feels like our first proper election, but I'm not sure how it interacts with the users we elected last year (in election #1 and election #2). Are we replacing a certain set of mods? Which ones? Are we just adding two more mods? All that page says is that there are "2 positions available".

Comment: Usually, mods get added on, as the existing ones are [elected for life](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/984/should-community-moderators-be-elected-for-life-or-have-terms) (or until resignation).

Comment: Yep, just pro tem mods are temporary.

Comment: 2 additional mods to our current staff

Answer (score 0):

Is two mods enough? We're still roughly the size Super User, yet they have 7 mods, 47 non-mods over 10k, and 15 non-mods over 20k; while this will only give us 6 mods, 22 over 10k, and 5 over 20k. Plus, according to Quantcast, our average visitor is younger, so we're likely to have more immature, low-quality content, I'd think.

Comment: How many of their 10 and 20k ers are also mods?

Comment: @RavenDreamer: They also have one mod over 20k and two over 10k, but that doesn't really matter, does it?

Comment: Nope. I was just curious.

Comment: how do you figure we're the same as superuser?  They have way more users/questions per day

Comment: @yx.: ...I'm not sure, actually...I think we decreased in size in some form since then.