# Will there be a 2013/14 moderator election?

Tags: discussion, moderators, meta

**Disclaimer:** I have nothing against the current mods. (No banhammers please).

---

I was reviewing the [2011](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1665/2011-community-moderator-election) & [2012](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3854/2012-community-moderator-election) Moderator elections, and noticed that they were both run in January of the respective year. Now, I only have a very general concept of time (so bear with me), but I believe January has already past for this year :(.

But not to worry! My sources tell me that ANOTHER January is rapidly approaching anyway, so whilst it may be a moot point this year, there's always next year!

Anyway, so my question is: Is there a Moderator Election planned for some point in the near future?

Comment: Cite these sources!  Yet another January?!  Preposterous!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Yes.](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/election/4)

Answer (score 16):

Elections are only held if moderators either resign or disappear for 6 months. Since this has not happened on Gaming, there is no need for a new election.

Comment: Ah, fair enough, I thought they were simply held every year. That makes sense though!

Comment: They are also held if the team asks if we need elections and we say yes. Last time they asked we didn't. If we felt that we badly needed elections we can probably get them just by asking with motivation.

Comment: @badp Correct. If you need halp, just give us a shout. Outside of requests from the mod team, we typically check in with every site once a year to see how they're doing and whether an election is needed.

Comment: So what you're saying is we need to 'disappear' some existing mods?